# fetch 5 latest rows from db using spring hibernatetemplate

Tags: hibernate, spring-orm

I want to fetch latest 5 rows from database using hibernate-template(Spring orm). I found that criteria can be used for this. But i dont know how to specify the limited number of rows(5) in criteria. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the latest 5 rows using an attribute of the table, lets assume some 'id' attribute, which is incremented for each new record. Having said that, you can set the ordering asc/desc and then limit the results.

ex:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
criteria.setMaxResults(5);
```

Update the criteria for the attribute you can use in your scenario.

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey Thanks for your reply. I am using Detached criteria. It seems "setMaxResults()" method is not available for  for Detached criteria. Please suggest.

Comment: @Sophiya Yes you are right setMaxResults is not available for the detached criteria. Im' afraid in that case, the only choice is to use Restrictions.sqlRestriction() add plain SQL expression to DetachedCriteria. Something like this :

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(YourClass.class)
  .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("LIMIT 1"));